# NSMutableArray is affecting the another NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have two `NSMutableArray`s, both getting the same data.  My problem is that when I assign the same data to both the mutable arrays from different dictionaries and perform operations on one `NSMutableArray`, it is affecting both arrays.

When I perform operations like `replaceObjectAtIndex:WithObject:`, the first time, the array is not affected but when the second replace is called both arrays have the replaced value. I think it is a reference issue.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Name of the `NSMutableArrays` is `helper.urlsRecording` and `helper.holdingArr`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:outputFileURL forKey:@"URL"];
[dict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"index"];
[dict2 setValue:outputFileURL forKey:@"URL"];
[dict2 setValue:@"1" forKey:@"index"];
[helper.urlsRecording addObject:dict];
[helper.holdingArr addObject:dict2];


[helper.urlsRecording replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:urlAr];//When this called second time, both the arrays is effected(helper.urlsRecording as well as helper.holdingArr).
```

How can I prevent the copying of the reference to another array?

Button Click:

```
if([button isSelected] == NO){

     NSLog(@"Url Recording : %@",helper.urlsRecording);
     [[helper.urlsRecording objectAtIndex:button.tag] removeObjectForKey:@"URL"];
     button.selected = YES;
     NSLog(@"Url Recording : %@",helper.urlsRecording);
}
else{
     [helper.urlsRecording replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:[helper.holdingArr objectAtIndex:button.tag]];
     button.selected = NO;
     NSLog(@"Url Recording : %@",helper.urlsRecording);

 }
```

Note: `NSMutableArray` is defined globally in a class to access.

Comment: how are you initializing this two arrays?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Check the edit please

Comment: Yes, I am initializing them thats why I am getting the data.

Comment: check helper.urlsRecording, helper.holdingArr what you store. Here you add the object to both arrays.

Comment: @NidhiPatel I have already tried several methods but the result is same. Both arrays is effected when I clicked the button second time. I have already checked the array they contain the data.

Comment: but how you are initializing your arrays, if you are assigning one to another maybe there is the issue

Comment: i dont know why u are adding two diff and same data dict in two diff array

Comment: @VikasRajput Because I was trying the solutions in diff way thats why.

Comment: then please make a Mutablecopy of your first Dict then replace in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your instance values are same for both dictionary.

So First create one `mutableDictionary` like below

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:outputFileURL forKey:@"URL"];
[dict setValue:@"1" forKey:@"index"];
```

And create second dictionary through mutableCopy, so instance will be different for both.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [dict mutableCopy];
```

After that you can add them in to `NSMutableArray` and update accordingly.

Comment: Problem is the same, second time the data is referenced to the array as same, the reference is still same when the button is clicked second time.

Comment: what are you doing on button click. Show me the code

Comment: This is because of [helper.urlsRecording replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:[helper.holdingArr objectAtIndex:button.tag]];. You are again replace the helper.urlsRecording array object to helper.holdingArr. So referencing will same again in both array. Try MutableCopy.

Comment: replace your line with [helper.urlsRecording replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:[[helper.holdingArr objectAtIndex:button.tag]mutableCopy]];

Comment: Ok I willl try this

Comment: Ok, do let me know the status

Comment: Your Welcome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a `copy`/`mutableCopy` dictionary & then add object to the `MutableArray`

```
[helper.urlsRecording addObject:[dict copy]];
[helper.holdingArr addObject:[dict2 copy]];
```

Comment: I will try this.